# Как преобразовать один вид ссылки в другую VK

Tags: php, html, vkontakte-api

Вообщем у меня в программе я получаю ссылки вот такого вида

https://vk.com/photo-151731953_456239065

Эта ссылка указывает на картинку в альбоме группе вк, но мне нужно отобразить эту картинку на своем сайте, но для html эта ссылка не подходит, а подходит вот такая

https://pp.userapi.com/c638822/v638822344/668d0/Lp04UVvdBP8.jpg

Эта ссылка получается после копирования url картинки первой ссылки. Как программно реализовать преобразование ссылок или как то по первой ссылки подгружать картинки на html страницу. Вариант скачать картинку и подгрузить не подходит. Может кто что подскажет ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитай [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/photos) вк API. А именно о запросе photos.getAlbums (возрщает список альбомов) и photos.get (возвращает список фотографий в альбоме). А там уже с json можно красиво получать ссылки на фото и потом выводить у себя на сайте)